I'm seeking a diplomatic answer to a question about Reform vs traditional customs re Kaddish Yatom
At a shiva minyan where two mourners were reciting kaddish while the others replied Amen, I was asked afterwards by a Reform Jew whose "minhag" is for the entire congregation to rise and recite the Kaddish Yatom in unison (ostensibly for "those for whom no-one is saying Kaddish") why were only those two saying it? My attempt at answering such a person pertained to the resultant failure to intently listen and respond to the actual mourner's public recitation that acknowledges faith in spite of trauma, anger, grief. I'd be interested in suggestions geared towards answering in good faith without causing discomfort or a major machloket.

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

If the whole congregation says kadish, who answers Amain?

@GershonGold that question applies to an Orthodox minyan of 10 mourners too (in shuls where multiple people say kaddish together)

Have you ever been to a Minyan where the whole Congregation was saying Kaddish? And maybe that is why some Shuls only one per person says Kaddish.

The whole shul saying kadish was ל"ע a common occurrence after the war

https://www.torahmusings.com/2014/01/may-multiple-people-say-kaddish-simultaneously/

@Gershon even two together is a modern reform and halachicly hard to explain. The difference between 9 to 10 isn't that big a deal: they say amen to each other

@Deuteronomy https://www.torahmusings.com/2019/12/mourners-kaddish-quality-or-quantity/

The "only 1" minhag was in place at a shul that I dropped in on during a trip to Israel, while I was in shloshim. When I stood to say ק"י the gabbai rushed over, asking me to be seated because P'loni was saying it. Without thinking I told him why I had risen - and then regretted it. I was a passing-through guest; the other gentleman was a member, in his year of mourning, and my kaddish "outranked" his. The gabbai said "oh!" and told P'loni to sit; all eyes and ears were then focused on me and the amens, while uplifting, did not erase my discomfort.

"It's a greater merit for the neshama when done the traditional way: because the mourner is getting others to say יְהֵא שְִׁמֵהּ רַבָּא in honor of the neshama, he is causing God's Name to be publicly sanctified on its behalf. Although this could still potentially happen when everyone says קַדִּישׁ together, it doesn’t work if they don't hear the mourner. In any event, their recitation is superfluous, but their response to him is essential."
"From the mourner's perspective, the recitation-response format conveys, ‘Hey guys, I'm mourning’ - ‘Hey friend, we're with you.’ Again, the congregants’ recitation is superfluous, but their response to him is essential."
